# A QR or Barcode Scanner App that allows you to POST stored results to webpage/API?

Tags: android, api, barcode

I apologize in advance if this belongs on a different stack community. Let's hope my question is specific enough.

A few years ago, I ran into a great little app on Android called Barcode Scanner Terminal. It is the only application I have found that makes it so easy to POST  stored results to a web page. Literally all you have to do is type the URL and whatever variables you want to record:

[image: screenshot]

I even wrote [a simple API to handle the information in ColdFusion](https://github.com/trosenow92).

My problem with this app is not its cost; it's the fact that you can't just buy it. You are forced into a subscription model, which makes working with clients more difficult than it has to be, relying on a 3rd party subscription.

With all the open source Scanner Apps out there, is there not one with this same functionality? Or something similar? Every web search I perform leads me back to one of two paid services.

Comment: While waiting for answers, you could check with [my list of barcode scanner apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode). My guess is some of the [barcode inventory apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory#group_34) could fit your needs.

Comment: Let me know if you find one that does. It is your website, after all.

Comment: Sorry, but please don't expect me having tried all those 14k+ apps listed there. I haven't. And if I knew which of them would meet your requirements, I had written an answer instead of a comment :) So you can either "sit it out" and wait until someone answers (which might take a little *if* someone does, no guarantees) – or meanwhile  skim over those lists and maybe write your own answer later. It's just an offer, nothing more.

Comment: It's just odd you would maintain a list and not know what's in it. Especially when it's more like 50 entries, not 14,000. I'll probably wind up writing my own thing in Ionic later anyway. Thanks.

Comment: All apps listed currently: 14408. It's not just the barcode apps :)